# How can I create a socket connection from the python signalr client to an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: python, asp.net, raspberry-pi, network-programming, signalr

I'm creating an ASP.NET web application that runs on a networked raspberry pi. 
I have also begun working on a tactile interface for the application and therefore need a connection between signalr and the server to make the app respond to commands from my tactile interface. 
Right now, I'm having trouble creating this connection between signalr and the host.

```
from requests import Session
from signalr import Connection
with Session() as session:
    connection = Connection("[link to web app]", session)
    connection.start()
```

Error 405: Method not allowed